# regex that allows 5-10 characters but can have spaces in-between not counting

Tags: regex

## Problem

Build a regex statement that allows the following:

1. minimum 5 characters
2. maximum 10 characters
3. can contain whitespace but whitespace does not increment character count
4. any non-whitespace characters increment character count

### Test Cases:

```
 expected_to_pass = ['testa', ' test a', 12342, 1.234, 'test a']
 expected_to_fail = [' test', 'test ', ' test ', '     ', 1234, 0.1, '           ','12345678901']
```

### Example regex statements and their purpose

**Allow 5-10 non-whitespace characters:**

```
[\S]{5,10}$
```

**Allow 5-10 characters regardless of whitespace:**

```
[\s\S]{5,10}$
```

I've been farting around with this for a few hours and cannot think of the best way to handle this.

Comment: any preference to programming language?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How's this?

```
\s*(?:[\w\.]\s*){5,10}+$
```

Or:

```
\s*(?:[\w\.]\s*){5,10}$
```

Also, if ANY non-whitespace character goes:

```
\s*(?:\S\s*){5,10}$
```

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/DsvRZY/3)

Comment: that wasn't in his test cases

Answer (score 2):

There is a wrong assumption in your question: `\w` doesn't match all non-space-characters, it matches word characters - this means letters, digits and the underscore. Depending on language and flags set, this might include or exclude unicode letters and digits. There are a lot more non-space-characters, e.g. `.` and `|`. To match space-characters one usually uses `\s`, thus `\S` matches non-space-characters.

You can use ^\s*(?:\S\s*){5,10}$ to check your requirements. You might be able to drop the anchors, if you use some kind of full match functionality (e.g. Java `.matches()` or Python `re.fullmatch`).

Depending on the language you use, you might not want to use a regex, but iterate over the string and check character for character. This should usually be faster than regex.

Pseudocode:

```
number of chars = 0
for first character of string to last character of string
  if character is space
     inc number of chars by 1
return true if number of chars between 5 and 10
```

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected my question with the proper regex statements.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:
`(\s*?\w\s*?){5,10}$`

It won't match `1.234` because . is not included inside \w set

If you need it to be included then:
<strike>`(\s*?[\w|\.]\s*?){5,10}$`</strike>
`(\s*?[\w\.]\s*?){5,10}$`

Cheers

Comment: the `|` in your character class represents a literal `|`, it does not represent an 'or' statement when in a character class.